# Remove installation details entirely

Tags: windows-7, vlc-media-player, uninstall

I heard that dell is voiding warranty for VLC installed laptops. They are saying like they have experts to check whether the user had installed VLC player or not. But my question is, even after uninstalling the operating system, whether it is possible to find the same?
If they can, then is there any way to remove all those installation details entirely from my laptop?
Please help.

Comment: Heard from who? There's no practical reason for VLC to be a reason to void a warranty

Comment: @JourneymanGeek It has something to do with VLC having an option to push the volume up to "400%", which apparently damages speakers (it did on my Lenovo atleast). Dont know how though

Answer (score 1):

This is related to Audio issues.
If you have problems with your speakers, blown or distorted sound and have VLC player or any 3rd party video/audio players then the OEM could void the warranty of the speaker and graphics.

Removing a program through 'Programs and features' removes the program, however, a registry may still be left on the machine, as could an entry in the 'Local Group Policy' firewall config.

If you have any doubts, check this thread;

[WARNING! installing VLC Media Player voids your speaker warranty!!!](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3517/t/19492918.aspx?PageIndex=2)

Sorry, forgot to mention, VLC and other 3rd party audio/visual players can also install a browser addon, that may not always be removed through the control panel.

Comment: even after reinstalling the operating system, the registry entry will remain the same?

Answer (score 0):

On OS X you can find support files with for example `mdfind org.videolan.vlc`, `mdfind vlc`, or `find / -name '*vlc*'`. Or try running `sudo opensnoop -n VLC` and use VLC for a while.

I found these files on my installation:

```
rm -r /Applications/VLC.app
rm -r ~/Library/Preferences/org.videolan.vlc*
rm -r ~/Library/Application\ Support/org.videolan.vlc
rm -r ~/Library/Caches/org.videolan.vlc
rm ~/Library/Saved\ Application\ State/org.videolan.vlc.savedState
rm ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/VLC_*.crash
rm ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/.VLC_*.crash.plist
rm ~/Library/Application\ Support/CrashReporter/VLC_*.plist
sudo rm /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/VLC_*.hang
sudo rm /var/db/BootCaches/*/app.org.videolan.vlc.playlist
```

There are probably also records of VLC in the Launch Services database, but you might be able to remove them by [rebuilding the database](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20071102084155353) after removing VLC.

When a program is installed by an installer, `bom` and `plist` files are added to `/var/db/receipts/` and an entry for the application is added to `/Library/Receipts/InstallHistory.plist`. `sudo pkgutil --forget $bundleid` removes the files in `/var/db/receipts/` but not the entry in `InstallHistory.plist`.

Comment: Question does seem specific to windows systems, in-spite of the rather odd tagging.